# Python, ошибка 'int' object is not subscriptable, подскажите как решить,это половина программы которая должна переводить 1 и 2 в опред сс

Tags: python

```
number1 = int(input('Введите число: '))
number2 = int(input('Введите число: '))
num1 = 0
while(number1):
   num1 = num1 + 1
num2 = 0
while(number2):
   num2 = num2 + 1
   number1Dec=0
   for i in range(0, num1):
       number1Dec=int(number1[i])*(8**(num1-i-1))
       print (number1Dec)
```

Comment: number1[i]  тут что вы от числа хотите ?

Comment: это цифра из числа, например при вводе 34, 3*(8^2-0-1), 4*(8^2-1-1)

Answer (score 2):

`number1` у вас число, зачем вы работает с ним как со строкой?

кроме того после того, как вы подсчитали сумму цифр числа `number1` оно у вас стало нулевым (вы же постоянно его на 10 делили)

P.S.

так и не понял, что программа должна делать :)
подсчитывает кол-во и сумму цифр двух вводимых чисел, а дальше какая-то запредельная магия

```
number1Dec=0+int(str(number1)[i])*int(8**(num1-i-1))
```

> я должен написать программу которая вычитает 2 числа одно из которых в
> 8ричной а другое 5тиричной сс, и записывает ответ в 8ричной сс. Мой
> план был таков что сначала переводим числа в 10тичную сс, отнимаем их
> и ответ переводим обратно в 8ричную сс – Chester 11 минут назад

@Chester, вся ваша задача выглядит так:

```
num_8 = int(input("введите число в 8ричной системе счисления: "), 8)
num_5 = int(input("введите число в 5ричной системе счисления: "), 5)

print(oct(num_8 - num_5)[2:])
```

:)

Comment: изначально программа подсчитывает кол-во цифр, после это значение используется в формуле которая должная переводить из 8ричной сс в 10 тичную сс.(алгоритм на подсчёт суммы цифр я забыл удалить + без него программа встаёт)

Comment: @Chester, так вы лучше опишите саму задачу дополнительно к вашему вопросу и подумаем как ее сделать лучше

Comment: ну изменил, а что бы вам было понятней опишу всю программу, я должен написать программу которая вычитает 2 числа одно из которых в 8ричной а другое 5тиричной сс, и записывает ответ в 8ричной сс. Мой план был таков что сначала переводим числа в 10тичную сс, отнимаем их и ответ переводим обратно в 8ричную сс

Comment: @Chester, ну подход конечно в лоб, но тоже работает - только вот где у вас перевод в 10ричную? нет

Comment: формула number1Dec=int(number1[i])*(8**(num1-i-1)) и должна переводить число из одной системы в другу, number1[i]-первая цифра(i нумерация),8**(num1-i-1) - возведения цифры в степень

Comment: @Chester - так вы считываете числа в 10ричной системе, когда от вас требуются числа в других системах. Посмотрите - я в свой ответ добавил код вашей задачи :)

Comment: проблема в том что задача стоит сделать все вычисления в ручную, через написанную формулу

Comment: @Chester, а переводить в 10ричную тоже через формулу надо или можно силами `int` справиться? в вашем примере `number1` и `number2` - это 10ричные числа, а не 8ричное и 5ричное, т.е. вначале сначала их вы должны в 10ричный вид перевести

Comment: по сути нет перевод в 10тичку можно внутри программы исполнить